# How to write if statement in Rails 4 as_json method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.I'm creating API databse where users can sign up from Facebook Graph API.
If user has no profile picture then the image_url is null.

After reading answers in SO I thought this is the correct way how to build custom json for my response.

I have created method as_json to render response when user is created with only parameters who should get returned.
This is the method how I'm creating json response:

```
  def as_json(options={}){ 
        id: self.id,
        first_name: self.first_name,
        last_name: self.last_name,
        auth_token: self.auth_token,
        image: {
            thumb: "http://domain.com" + self.profile_image.thumb.url
        }
    }
    end
```

This method above gives me an error: `no implicit conversion of nil into String`.

I need to give absolute image url path if the image exists in my db, but i don't need to give this parameter in response if image url is null in my database.
How can I write if statement inside this as_json method?
I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
  def as_json(options={}){ 
        id: self.id,
        first_name: self.first_name,
        last_name: self.last_name,
        auth_token: self.auth_token,
        if !self.profile_image.thumb.url == nil
            image: {
                thumb: "http://domain.com" + self.profile_image.thumb.url
            }
        end     
    }
    end
```

---

With the help from Jorge de los Santos I've managed to make it pass `no implicit conversion of nil into String` error with this code:

```
def as_json(options={})
  response = {  id: self.id,
                first_name: self.first_name,
                last_name: self.last_name,
                auth_token: self.auth_token }
  if !self.profile_image.thumb.url == nil
    image = "http://domain.com" + self.profile_image.thumb.url
    response.merge(image: {thumb: image })
  end
  response
end
```

But now all the users are returned without image parameter even when he has a image url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine except when you try to merge image key, merge function is not working as you expect, check the followingt to understand:

```
 hash = {a: 1, b:2 }
 hash.merge(b: 3)
 puts hash   #{a: 1, b:2 }
 hash = hash.merge(b: 3)
 puts hash   #{a: 1, b:2, c: 3 }
```

so you will need to modify your code by changing this line:

```
response.merge(image: {thumb: image })
```

to

```
response = response.merge(image: {thumb: image })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Jbuilder**

When you are building a complex json object, it's better to use jbuilder, I'll assume the model is called 'User'

Create a template called `show.json.jbuilder`

```
json.id @user.id
json.first_name @user.first_name
json.last_name @user.last_name
json.auth_token @user.auth_token
unless @user.profile_image.thumb.url.nil?
  json.image do |image|
    image.thumb "http://domain.com#{@user.profile_image.thumb.url}"
  end
end
```

I would recommend creating a helper for the image url, so we could for example call something like

```
json.image @user.full_profile_image_url
```

---

**Using as_json**

As for your own method (using as_json) you could create a method that returns the full image hash

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image
    { thumb: "http://domain.com#{profile_image.thumb.url}" }
  end
end
```

Then in the as json call the method

```
@user.to_json(
  only: %i(id first_name last_name auth_key),
  methods: :image
)
```

This will call the image method and set it's value inside a key called 'image'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use logic inside a hash key, you can declare the variable before returning the hash, or you can use the full statement inside the value of the hash. But I think this is more readable.

```
def as_json(options={})
  response = {  id: self.id,
                first_name: self.first_name,
                last_name: self.last_name,
                auth_token: self.auth_token }
  image = "http://domain.com" + self.profile_image.thumb.url
  response.merge!({image: {thumb: image }}) unless self.profile_image.thumb.url
  response
end
```

Comment: Ah you want an optionak key!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it, but it doesn't work if the image url is null. I got the error:
`no implicit conversion of nil into String` where I can't do `"http://domain.com" + self.profile_image.thumb.url` if url is empty. But this field can be empty if the user has no profile picture in Facebook and because of this I wanted to include image url only if it exists in database.

Comment: that is because you are calling a method into nil. That is not stated in your question. Update it with the stack trace of the error.

Comment: I've edited my question and also added a code with update in my progress.

Comment: You can, with ternary operators... `condition ? "output if true" : "output if false"`